# Serialize hashCode() with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, hashcode

I have a POJO which I would like to serialize to JSON using Gson. I can't modify the POJO for some reason, but I would like to include the calculated usual Java `hashCode` into the output as an extra key. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why not to simply store it as a field? If your POJO is immutable, you can just compute it and assign in constructor. The field and actual hashCode() result would not even get inconsistent.

Comment: I can't modify the POJO.. And I guess I would need to reassign that value every time I call any setter

Comment: Not if your POJO was immutable (i.e. no setters). But yeah, you're right, the suggestion doesn't really make sense when you can't modify the POJO.

Comment: You could provide a facade for your POJO proxying to an actual instance passed in constructor. While providing the same API as the POJO you can add arbitrary further stuff like hash code via a public final field or a getter.

Comment: Do you want the hashCode for only one class, or if the POJO has non-json-primitive values in it, should those have hashCodes as well?

Comment: The POJO has it's hashCode implemented in a way that calculates hash considering the non-primitive fields as well.